# PHP Array - Adding elements to array with numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code.  What I am trying to do is build an array of all the values, and then use array_unique to strip out the duplicates.  However, it is creating multiple arrays like so:

> Array ( [0] => 153 ) Array ( [0] => 125 [1] => 153 ) Array ( [0] =>
>   167 [1] => 125 )

When what I want is

> [0] => 153 [1] => 125 [2] => 153 [3] => 167 [4] => 125

```
public function __construct()
    {
    $cat_arr = array();
    $merged = array();
    $cat = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('cat', '0');
            if($cat !== "0")
            {
            $cat_arr[] = $cat;
            $result = ee()->db->select('parent_id')
                ->from('exp_categories')
                ->where('cat_id',$cat)
                ->get();
                $parent = $result->row('parent_id');
                if($parent !== "0")
                {
                    $cat_arr[] = $parent;
                }
            }
            print_r($cat_arr);
            //Array ( [0] => 153 ) Array ( [0] => 125 [1] => 153 ) Array ( [0] => 167 [1] => 125 ) 
    }
```

If anyone can offer any solution to this, I would be deeply grateful.

Comment: Maybe, you get the full `row` (it may comes in array) instead of just the column, could you use `$result->column` instead of `$result->row` ? (As I don't understand how you are getting the values).

Comment: The values are just strings from the database, they are properly populated, i.e. "153", "125"

Comment: The problem is that the loop is creating multiple instances of the $cat_arr array it seems.

Comment: i think the problem is `$cat_arr[] = $cat;` and `$cat_arr[] = $parent;` .this is two times and based on condition i can definitely tell that some time it run two time and some time it runs once. which is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your code. The issue is that you are running print_r within your loop. Move print_r to the end and you will see that your array is being generated exactly as you want it to be.

Comment: Where did you found the loop?

Comment: are you serious? where `print_r()` is in loop?

Comment: The code snippet pasted is not her full code. The output suggests a loop as well as what she is asking to do, but she did not paste the loop. I cannot believe the output that she is receiving can be achieved without a loop.

Comment: The print_r is being requested after both loops have exited and the array should be fully populated.  It does return 3 separate arrays from what I can see...?

Comment: @KristinaAnderson - you need to post your full code. The snippet you posted is not useful and will confuse everyone who is trying to help.

Comment: PressingonAlways, both loops are there, and the print_r statement is being generated after both loops exit.  This is the full code generating the array.

Comment: @KristinaAnderson Can you please provide the full code so we can help you a lot

Comment: @KristinaAnderson there is no loops in the code snippet you pasted in your question. Please double check.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, do I need to wrap it in while($cat = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('cat', '0')) {

Comment: OK good concept but $cat is not an array, it is grabbing the category IDs one by one